# aligning grid height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page am having 2 sections.
1.Div with dynamic content,Height of the div will change according to the content.
2.A Flexigrid to show some content.

As of now my flexigrid size is constant irrespective of the 1st DIV content.When 1st div content is very less as flexigrid height is constant so much of free space left over after the grid.
Here my challange is to arrange flexigrid height so as to cover the full page depends on the 1st DIV height.

[image]

I wrote some code using offset.which is working fine but not optimum.

> Here is the code

```
 function calcHeight() {



     var grid = $('.flexigrid').offset().top + $('.flexigrid').height();
     var footer = $('#footer').offset().top;

     var req_height;
     //checking if page has a scroll or not.
     if (grid > footer) {
         req_height = $('.bDiv').height() - $('.flexigrid').offset().top;
     } else {
         req_height = $('.bDiv').height() + footer - grid;

     }


     return req_height;


 }

 function setHeight() {

     var req_height = calcHeight();

     var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
     if (!styleElement) {
         styleElement = document.createElement('style');
         styleElement.type = 'text/css';
         styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
     }
     var newStyle = '.bDiv{height:' + req_height + 'px!important}';
     styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
 }
```

Am calling `setHeight()` function which in turn will call `calcHeight` to calculate required height.
Please let me know if it can be done in any other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var dynamicContentHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
var footerHeight = $("#footer").height();


var gridheight = windowheight - headerHeight - footerHeight - dynamicContentHeight;

$("#gridheight").css("height", gridheight);
```